# Join between three tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have 3 tables and I want to fetch users data from it.

**Table 1 :** `frei_session`

```
username    session_id

Prince      51
Dilip       49
Sumit       50
```

**Table 2 :** `friendrequest`

```
requestTo   requestFrom     status

49              50              C
50              51              C
49              51              P
```

**Table 3 :** `users`

```
accountId    userImage

49           image_49.jpg
50           image_50.jpg
51           image_51.jpg
```

**friendrequest** table show relationship between users where **C** stands for **Complete** and **P** stands for **Pending**. means if `status = C` both are friends and if `status = P` request is pending.

**frei_session** table display all online users of website.

**users** table stored the path of images

I want to show the image of user along with it's id.

suppose user **49** is online

```sql
SELECT  IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.userName, b.userName) username,
        IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.session_ID, b.session_ID) Session_ID
FROM    friendRequest a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON a.requestTo = b.session_ID
        INNER JOIN frei_session c
            ON a.requestFrom = c.session_ID
WHERE   a.status = 'C' AND
        49 IN (a.requestTo, a.requestFrom)
```

This query show me output like this

```
username    session_id

Sumit           50
```

but I want output like this

```
username    session_id    userImage

Sumit       50            image_50.jpg
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole query in a subquery and join it with table `users`

```
SELECT  x.*, y.userImage
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.userName, b.userName) username,
                    IF(a.RequestTo = 49, c.session_ID, b.session_ID) Session_ID
            FROM    friendRequest a
                    INNER JOIN frei_session b
                        ON a.requestTo = b.session_ID
                    INNER JOIN frei_session c
                        ON a.requestFrom = c.session_ID
            WHERE   a.status = 'C' AND
                    49 IN (a.requestTo, a.requestFrom)
        ) x INNER JOIN users y
            ON x.session_ID = y.accountID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae31b/1)